# How can i sync my indexedDB Data to my MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema, indexeddb

How can i sync data from IndexedDB to my MongoDB.

I open my IndexedDB like this:

```
    const requestDB = indexedDB.open('meineDatenbank', 1);

    requestDB.onerror = function(event) {
      console.log('Fehler beim Öffnen der IndexedDB-Datenbank');
    };

    requestDB.onsuccess = function(event) {
      const db = event.target.result;
    
    let transaction = db.transaction(["meinObjectStore"]);
    let store = transaction.objectStore("meinObjectStore");
    let request = store.getAll();

    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
      const dataNew = event.target.result;
      
      console.log(dataNew)
}}
```

And in the console my data will displayed like this:

```
0:{id: 0, name: 'Peter', date: '2023-01-04', city: 'Bremen', status: 'offline', description: 'fsdfdsfds', …}
1:{id: 1, name: 'Peter', date: '2023-01-04', city: 'Hamburg', status: 'offline', description: 'fsdfdsfds', …}
2:{id: 2, name: 'Peter', date: '2023-01-04', city: 'Berlin', status: 'offline', description: 'fsdfdsfdsfdsfdsf', …}
3:{id: 4, name: 'Peter', date: '2203-01-01', city: 'Hannover', status: 'new', …}
4:{id: 5, name: 'Peter', date: '2023-01-01', city: 'Cuxhavenn', status: 'new', …}
5:{id: 6, name: 'Peter', date: '2023-01-01', city: 'Cuxhavenn', status: 'new', …}
6:{id: 7, name: 'Peter', date: '2023-01-01', city: 'Cuxhavenn', status: 'new', …}
7:{id: 8, name: 'Peter', date: '0302-02-01', city: 'Bonn', status: 'new', …}
8:{id: 9, name: 'Peter', date: '0203-01-01', city: 'Kreuzberg', status: 'new', …}
9:{id: 10, name: 'Peter', date: '2012-01-01', city: 'Hamburg', status: 'new', …}
10:{id: 11, name: 'Peter', date: '2013-01-01', city: 'Giresun', status: 'offline', …}
11:{id: 12, name: 'Peter', date: '2013-01-01', city: 'New York', status: 'offline', …}
12:{id: 13, name: 'Peter', date: '2013-01-01', city: 'Boston', status: 'offline', …}
13:{id: 14, name: 'Peter', date: '2013-01-01', city: 'Paris', status: 'offline', …}
14:{id: 15, name: 'Peter', date: '2013-01-01', city: 'London', status: 'offline', …}
15:{id: 16, name: 'Peter', date: '2015-01-01', city: '', status: 'offline', …}
length: 16
[[Prototype]]:Array(0)
```

i use the mongoose schema for my MongoDB Database, which is like this:

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose")

const IMGSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    imgBase64:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    status:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    city:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        required:true
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
})

const img=new mongoose.model("pictureData", IMGSchema)

module.exports=img
```

Normally i have a `/upload` route to send Data from a form Tag to MongoDB:

```
router.post("/upload", async (req,res) => {
  try {
    await img.create(req.body)
   if(true){
    res.status(200).json({message:true})
   }else{
    res.status(200).json({message:false})
   }
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      res.status(500).json({message: error.message})
  }
  console.log("upload wurde durchgeführt")
})
```